# efficiency of CUDA Scalar and SIMD video instructions

Tags: cuda, nvidia, simd

The throughput of SIMD instruction is lower that 32-bits integer arithmetic.
In case of SM2.0 (Scalar instruction only versions) is 2 time lower.
In case of SM3.0 is 6 time lower.

What is a cases when suitable to use them ?

Answer (score 4):

If your data is already packed in a format that is handled natively by a SIMD video instruction, then it would require multiple steps to unpack it so that it can be handled by an ordinary instruction.

Furthermore, the throughput of a SIMD video instruction should also be multiplied by the number of actual operations performed when comparing it with ordinary arithmetic operations.

For example, for the instruction [vadd4](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#simd-video-instructions-vadd4-vsub4-vavrg4-vabsdiff4-vmin4-vmax4), 4 integer adds are being performed, on a packed 32-bit quantity (4 byte integer quantities).  In order to duplicate this behavior with ordinary integer adds, a fairly complicated sequence of instructions would be needed to unpack the data into 4 `int` quantities, do 4 integer adds, and then re-pack the result.  If you attempted to do it with a single integer add, carry from one result could corrupt the next result.  `vadd4` also offers clamping abilities and other behavior not available with integer add.

In the case of SM2.0, just the ratio of 4 operations performed by the `vadd4` vs. the 4 integer adds necessary on unpacked data would make it attractive.  In the case of SM3.0, when the unpacking and packing are added to the ordinary integer add routine, the `vadd4` looks attractive.  The situation becomes even more attractive [with cc 5.0](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions).

Comment: In most cases , for example image filters, starting from 8-bits input and required several operations on data more that 8-bits (in general up to 16). From my point of view vadd4 usefully only on the end of such process. Most used will be vadd2. Also if intermediate values doesn't exceed 16 bits and can be positive the "SIMD like" additions or shifts can be performed in ordinary arithmetic. In addition may be usefully [multibyte arithmetic](http://www.hackersdelight.org/corres.txt)

Comment: For some use cases you may need to re-factor the computation a bit to make good used of the SIMD instructions. The following paper shows the application of four-way byte-wise SIMD operations to a key computation in computational biology, leading to substantial speedups: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/14/117

Comment: NVIDIA also provides to registered developers [a set of inline PTX SIMD functions](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/assets/simd-functions) which are hardware accelerated on Kepler, which may be of interest to those considering the SIMD video instructions.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: Actually those SIMD device functions are now part of CUDA proper, see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD

Comment: I don't see the problem with unpacking? It's not a bit field. You could just do a `reinterpret_cast` from `uint32_t *` to `uint8_t *`, and then access each byte easily without bit shifting, couldn't you? "more attractive with cc 5.0.", I don't see it? Doesn't "Multiple instruct." mean that the throughput got even slower, not even specifying anymore, how slow it will be?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to skin the cat.. You might be able to do some things in-place without unpacking or shifting.  But you won't get the throughput/efficiency unless you treat it as a packed operation handled by the intrinsic.